# Replacing cloud values with NA in a raster stack

Tags: raster, r, landsat

I am removing clouds from a raster stack of 768 pixel_qa bands which are provided by USGS as part of surface reflectance product. The details of raster stack (qa) are:

```
> qa
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 2520, 2714, 6839280, 768  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent     : 205755, 287175, 3950955, 4026555  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

Before I use this qa raster stack to mask NDVI stack, I use the following code to replace cloud values to NA:

```
> qa[qa %in% c(224, 480, 992)] <- NA
```

where 224 is cloud pixel value for Landsat 4-7 and 480 & 992 for Landsat 8.

The code runs forever! What could be wrong here?

Comment: You have over 5 billion cells in that stack. Perhaps you haven't waited long enough. How long does it take on a single layer? Multiply by 768. Quick test on my laptop means it would take about 6 minutes. How's your patience?

Comment: @Spacedman yeah it has 6.8 million cells. I waited for more than 3 hours! I guess it shouldn't take that long.

Comment: It has 6.8 million cells in each of the 768 layers making 5 billion in total. It might be quicker to do each layer separately since then not so much will be loaded into memory at once... Hmmm...

Comment: @Spacedman ah! It makes sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it a layer at a time in a for loop seems much faster. Here's an example.

Make a 500x500 raster with values from 1 to 200:

```
> set.seed(999); r = raster(matrix(sample(200, 500*500,TRUE),500,500))
```

Make that into a stack of five of them:

```
> s = stack(r,r,r,r,r)
```

Make two copies:

```
> s1 = s
> s2 = s
```

The first one, replace all the values with a single replacement:

```
> system.time({s1[s1 %in% c(22,33,44)] <- NA})
   user  system elapsed 
  1.716   0.000   1.730
```

The second one, loop over `nlayers(s2)`

```
> system.time({for(i in 1:nlayers(s2)){s2[[i]][s2[[i]] %in% c(22,33,44)] <- NA}})
   user  system elapsed 
  0.117   0.000   0.118
```

Ten times faster. The resulting values are identical:

```
> identical(s1[],s2[])
[1] TRUE
```

Although the raster objects aren't. Hmm...

```
> s1 = s
> class(s)
[1] "RasterStack"
attr(,"package")
[1] "raster"
```

So when I created it `s1` was a `RasterStack`:

```
> class(s1)
[1] "RasterStack"
attr(,"package")
[1] "raster"
```

I do the replacement and...

```
> s1[s1 %in% c(22,33,44)] = NA
> class(s1)
[1] "RasterBrick"
attr(,"package")
[1] "raster"
```

Its now a `RasterBrick`. This might explain the slowness - R is creating another object the same size and possible now you have two copies in memory. Doing the layer at a time method doesn't change the object to a `RasterBrick` so might be more efficient in its memory handling.

Comment: Thank you for the illustration of the problem. I will create a for loop and apply over the raster stack.